# Jquery to change text between normal and vertical

Tags: jquery, css

I am creating a custom graduation stole configurator. In this configurator a customer can enter a line of text like "Class of 2004". I need to have a button that changes the text between two formats...

1. Standard Orientation which would just be: Class of 2004
2. Vertical Orientation which would be:

C

l

a

s

s

o

f

2

0

0

4

What would be the best way to do this where I can swap back and forth between the two orientations? My idea was to save the original orientation somewhere in a hidden div so I could recall it at any time and then when they click the vertical text button, convert spaces to "
" and then add a single 
 between every character. It sounds like a kind of hacky way to do it so I'm trying to figure out how other people would do it. Need it to work with IE8+ too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One approach would be with the jQuery plugin [lettering.js](http://letteringjs.com/). This plugin wraps each letter (or word) in a span, and allows you to manipulate text by individual words or letters...

So, you can do this, and just use jquery to toggle clear:both, or some such thing on each letter.

[Here's a jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/hcBD9/)